# launch emulator with newly built source Music application

Tags: android-emulator, makefile, launch, android-music-player

I have built ICS source using "make -j4", then I have modified the Music application in the source code ("packages/apps/Music") & built it successfully using "make Music". It generates "out/target/product/generic/system/app/Music.apk". Now I want to launch an emulator with this new source & test my changes in Music app.
How to do this ? Do i need to rebuild entire source code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here:-

http://devtcg.blogspot.in/2009/03/building-running-and-debugging-android.html

Also set your path:-

export PATH=$PATH:/home/yourname/android-sdk/tools:/home/yourname/android-sdk/platform-tools

U may also need to :-

export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/rXX  (your Android SDK path), 
if u get an error like "unknown skin name"

U can also launch emulator with sdcard as:-

mksdcard -l mySdCard 1024M newsdcard.img

emulator -partition-size 256 -sdcard newsdcard.img -skin WXGA720